# Real time message receiving from server (Database - MySQL, Frontend -Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, angularjs, ajax

My code is working perfectly , But i need to refresh my page to get 
new message . I want the real time message.

Angular controller's function -

```
$scope.getAllMessages = function() {
    $scope.messages=[];
    restservice.get('', "api/v1/message/getMessageList").then(function(response) {
        if (response != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $scope.messages.push(response[i]);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

My UI looks like -

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages" class="{{(message.me == '1')? 'me' : 'other'}}">
    <div>
        {{message.userMessage}}
    </div>
</li>
```

Please make it simple for me and give me a proper guideline/tutorial to do it. I'm bad at front end.

Comment: Why do u need to refresh whole page? Just call  **$scope.getAllMessages** function after some interval. Or if you need real time messaging like push notifications then go with service worker. Limitation with service worker is that work on limited browsers.

Comment: How to call function after interval?? Can you show me an example??

Comment: Place somewhere in your controller **setTimeout(function(){$scope.getAllMessages()},5000)** . Here 5000 is milliseconds.

Comment: Look this Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/ew3I88PLuBrm7tCkhq5R?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).
Javascript has built-it WebSocket object wich you can use. And you also need to handle websockets on your server side. But for messaging websockets or [long polling requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560872/how-does-long-polling-work-javascript) looks as more useful technologies, as for me.

WebSockets are very simple and if you want real-time, they could be useful. But you would have to implement websockets backend on your server. Here is a sample of WS usage from the JS side:

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver", "protocolOne");
exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

This is example from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Answer (score 0):

You need to call getAllMessages method on interval basis so that you get live data or real time data

[Link here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

check with the above link for Example how to implement

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting ALL messages again i will considere do another .get maybe like this:

```
$interval(getLastMessagesFrom, 1000);


function getLastMessagesFrom () {

    // Extract the last message_ID from $scope.messages, to do this maybe
    // you will need to change your backend code to add the message ID in
    // the message object. This deppends on your backend code & backend
    // message response.

    var last_message_id = $scope.messages[$scope.messages.length-1].id;


    restservice.get('', "api/v1/message/getMessageList/" + last_message_id).then(function(response) {
        if (response != null) {

            // Now make sure that your server only returns messages with
            // ID higher than last_message_id

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $scope.messages.push(response[i]);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Anyways this is still a bad practice if you have a lower time interval (1000 = 1 second) and a lot of concurrent users.

Considere use sockets to avoid repeated and unecessary calls.

Answer (score 0):

use nodeJS's sockets 
where you can achieve real-time experience.

e.g
once you inserted to database,you can fire JS command to emit msg realtime

**io.sockets.connected[setsocketid].emit("clssifiedMessage", {msg:"Hi!!!how are yyou?" });**